# Disable a particular CouchDB user's password temporarily

Tags: authentication, couchdb

Can I disable login for a particular CouchDB user while leaving their [user doc](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/intro/security.html#users-documents) in the authentication database?

This question is similar to [How to temporarily disable particular user in couchdb?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56919356/how-to-temporarily-disable-particular-user-in-couchdb), but in that case the actual question was how to "temporarily disable particular user *read/write access*" [emphasis mine].

What I am trying to do is to completely prevent a user from login until a password is set.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior isn't necessarily guaranteed by the CouchDB maintainers in the future, but inspired by the [Unix password lockout feature](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/558592/42732) it seems possible to do this in practice by replacing at least the `derived_key` field with a bogus value like `"*"` or `"!"`.

For example, this user could login in by providing a certain password:

```
{
  "_id": "org.couchdb.user:test",
  "name": "test",
  "roles": [],
  "type": "user",
  "password_scheme": "pbkdf2",
  "iterations": 10,
  "derived_key": "e7666ce1536488d8c0ceb2b2e9baf25d83e1d720",
  "salt": "8b7ea88d05181c77553169354decb0b7"
}
```

By replacing the scheme-relevant fields with garbage data, the user is no longer able to log in while the CouchDB logs do not register any particular upset/crash:

```
{
  "_id": "org.couchdb.user:test",
  "name": "test",
  "roles": [],
  "type": "user",
  "password_scheme": "pbkdf2",
  "iterations": 10,
  "derived_key": "!",
  "salt": "-some other random nonce-"
}
```

I have not completely confirmed, though, how this gets handled inside of CouchDB. My read of the [authenticate logic](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/ab93b155095643ab13f3779abc6c948fe273fe4b/src/couch/src/couch_httpd_auth.erl#L435-L448) and how it interacts with the [its pbkdf2 implementation](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/7597abf850870bb63e115ec004106b403a9be42c/src/couch/src/couch_passwords.erl#L116-L124) is that the stored `derived_key` is compared as a raw byte string to the re-calculated one and thus there would be no way to generate a collision. So this should always disable the account. (As opposed to a situation where, say, the stored `"!"` is optimistically expected to be hex of a certainly length and gets quietly "coerced" to a buffer of all zeroes in any case where parsing fails or something…then it *might* be possible to find an input password such that the result looks correct. Leaving the salt set to a new random-but-valid nonce value would presumably keep a bypass like that prohibitive in practice.)

Comment: This should work. Changing the `password_scheme` to something like "pbkdf2-disabled", or similar, should also work, as would changing the document id not to begin with "org.couchdb.user:".